# Python - File processing ( Write Method )

Tags: python

I am having trouble while writing file using python

```
from validate_email import validate_email

result=open('output1.tsv','wb')

f=open('input.csv','r')

y=[]

result.write('Email_address\tEmail_validation\n')

for i in f:
    y.append(i.replace('\n',''))

for j in y:
    try:
         val=validate_email('%s'%j, verify=True)
    except:
         val = "Check Again"
    result.write('%s\t%s\n'%(j,val))
    print j,val
```

Here the variable x has some operation , It may take some time to process it.

variable y has more than a count of 500 ( input file contains 700 rows ).

But after run this program around 120 only written in the output file.

Comment: I suspect that there is a loss of the original indentation of your code, exactly where it matters the most, following the `try ... except` clause.  I can guess that you don't write the results as often as it should be becauase of a problem with `try ... except` but if the indentation is wrong... (please edit your post, don't try to explain in a comment!)

Comment: It seems that all the `try except` is unnecessary, are you using `validate_email` from "https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email" ? The only possible answer is `True` or `False`...

Comment: please check it now.

Comment: can you give an example of line that is not written but you expect it to?
in addition, are you sure validate_email raise an exception when not validate?

Comment: Sometime the module validate_email interrupted because of Time Out error, Because of that I used the Exception handling

Answer (score 1):

A more idiomatic python is

```
emails    = [l.strip() for l in open('input.csv','r').readlines()]
valid     = [str(validate_email(addr, validate=1)) for addr in emails]
validated = ['\t'.join(addr_val) for addr_val in zip(emails, valid)]

with of as open('output.tsv'):
    of.write('Email_address\tEmail_validation\n')
    of.write('\n'.join(validated)) # if needed ; of.write('\n')
```

#### Edit in response to the *late* further info from the OP

To take into account the possibility of a `TimeoutError` exception, that is likely raised by the `smtp` module, you can write an helper function

```
def validate_no_timeout(address):
    try:
        response = str(validate_email(address, validate=1))
    except TimeoutError:
        response = "Time Out"
    return response
```

and rewrite the second line in my original post to read

```
valid     = [validate_no_timeout(addr) for addr in emails]
```

NB: in the OP I see a generic reference to a *Time Out error*. In my code I catched the `TimeoutError` exception, in lack of exact info from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You have use a string when writing to file try changing it to:

```
t.write('%d\t%d\n'%(j,x))
```

If this doesn't fix it, try expanding the code in your question so we can help more.